# I7-3630QM Processor clock ratings

Tags: laptop, cpu, overclocking

I'm researching a laptop for college, and have a loose set of system specs. I found a laptop that meets most of the requirements with little or no modifications, except the processor isn't what I'm looking for at a "base" level.

I'm looking for a 3.0 - 3.3 GHz processor, i7 or better. The laptop I'm looking at has a processor listed as `Intel Core I7-3630QM 2.4GHz Turbo up to 3.4GHz` in the product description. Is this saying that the processor is overclockable to 3.4 GHz, and would it severely shorten the lifespan of the processor to be overclocked to 3.0 GHz about a third of the time it's on? And is it safe to overclock a laptop that much?

Comment: [Turboboost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost) is automatic "On Demand" overclocking. Basically whenever the system needs more power than it is getting, turboboost will boost the processer until it is no longer receiving the demand for that extra power or exceeds its operating limits. This is not quite the same as a 24/7 overclock, which can be risky on laptops due to their **limited cooling capacity**.

Comment: Also look into a 15" laptop. I had a 17" laptop which was an absolute nightmare in classes. I eventually invested in a 14" Toshiba Portege which, while being much slower, was much more convenient and didn't run out of power when I wasn't near an outlet.

Comment: Your not going to be able to overclock your laptop.  The firmware won't even allow it unless you purchase one that specifically allows it which normally comes at a cost. If money is no object they exits, otherwise, the i7-3630QM is a decent CPU.  Your not going to a great deal that out performs it in a laptop except perhaps a Haswell part